geometrically understanding linear system $|2p|$ on an elliptic curve
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve (over the complex numbers), and let $p$ be a point on $E$. What does the linear system $|2p|$ look like geometrically? If $x \in \mathcal{O}(2p)$ is non-constant, then $div(x)=q_1+q_2-2p$ for some points $q_1, q_2$ (I don't know if they have to be distinct) then I know that as a set
$$|2p|=\{[ div(1+ax) + 2p: a \in \mathbb{C}]\} \cup \{2p \}$$
(not sure why curly braces are not rendering, so using [] instead).
Since $div(1+ax) + 2p$ consists of two points, as $a$ varies we get a pair lines in the elliptic curve, is that right? Basically, I don't understand how to think of linear systems.

The group law of Weil divisor is same as group law of elliptic curve itself. So $|q_1+q_2|\sim |2p|$ if $q_1+q_2=2p$ under the group law of elliptic curve (imagine $p$ is the middle point of $q_1,q_2$) . And there are 4 possible $q$ s.t. $2p=2q$ which indicates the linear system gives a double cover $C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ ramified at 4 points.
